# Marketing Cloud - Multiple queries targeting the same data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, query, python

It's a little disappointing that there is no way to track the status of a query, I guess there is a SOAP API for that but I am a REST/python guy.

What happens when I start a query that overwrites a data extension, and before that completes if I start another query which also overwrites the same data extension?

Not that I want to do it, but after I ran my query, I didn't see my table populated. I was not sure whether the query was still running or it just failed, so I made some modifications to the query and ran it again.

1. How do I know if a query is still running? Is there a REST API for
   it?
2. What happens technically when two queries running at the same
   time try to overwrite the data on the same data extension?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to monitor the progress of a query is to:

1. Create a Scheduled Automation in Automation Studio
2. Insert a Query Activity on the Automation Canvas and select your query
3. Save the Automation
4. Click Run Once
5. Click the Activity Tab
6. Click on the refresh icon to see the status

If two queries are running at the same time, whichever query completes first will overwrite the Data Extension.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 3 potential solutions to that:

1. **Automation**: As per Eliot's excellent (as always) suggestion, you can put it in an Automation. Now, the *status icon* has been unreliable for me in the past, and who wants to check the status the whole time anyway? Instead, you can also set an email notification when the automation has ran. When you are on your Automation, click on "Activity" and add your email address under "Run Completion". This will make it even easier on yourself.
2. **Addon for SFMC**: There is also [an app that lets you create SQL queries through a GUI](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-4) and - more to the point - it has a preview mode where it shows exactly what the status is ("Queued", "Processing",...). See screenshots for statuses:

[image: requested]
[image: query queued]

3. **Programmatically**: Thru the API, it is possible to [create Query Activities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_query_activity.htm), run them (you will need to create a "Task" for this), and [check on the status](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/taskresult.htm?search_text=task). If you want to do this via a Node app, then some of the api calls you need to make are also available in this [open source project](https://github.com/DESelectMC/sfmc).

Let me know if that helps.